# How to hide navigation bar

Tags: android, popupwindow, navigationbar, android-popupwindow, android-navigation-bar

I've got a promblem with Android app.

I use this code to hide navigation bar.

```
public class Initer {
    public static void fullScreen(Window window) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            View decor = window.getDecorView();
            fullScreen(decor);
        } else {
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    public static void fullScreen(View decor) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |    
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I show `PopupWindow` or `Dialog` up, navigation bar will come up again.

I tried do this

```
PopupWindow popupWindow =new PopupWindow(getWindow().getContext());
View popupWindowView = LayoutInflater.from(getWindow().getContext()).
        inflate(R.layout.dialog_interval_insert, null);
Initer.fullScreen(popupWindowView);

...

popupWindow.showAsDropDown(button_start);
```

to hide navigation bar when `PopupWindow` showing up. But it doesn't work. When I call the `PopupWindow`, the navigation bar will show up then hide again. And when I `dismiss()` it, navigation bar will be there.

How can I hide navigation bar permanently in Whole application?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
public void FullScreen_Activity(Activity activity) {
    activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

and change StatusBar Color with

```
public void setStatusBarColor(Activity activity, int RecColor) {
        if (isApi21()) {
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            // finally change the color
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, RecColor));
        }
    }
```

and how to use FullScreen_Activity method

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getMethod().FullScreen_Activity(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think is code is how to hide action bar and status bar. But I just want to hide the Navigation Bar.